# React breadcrumbs component implementation

Tags: javascript, react.js

I've written a breadcrumbs component (`RouteBreadcrumbs`) that has the following features/behavior:

- Takes in an array of labels for each breadcrumb (ex: `['Settings', 'System settings', 'Display']`. The component displays these labels in
  the order that they're placed in in the array.
- Assumes that the last label in the array represents the currently viewed page. For the rest of the labels that come before it, the user
  can click on one in order to navigate to that page.
- Gets the current path it is rendered in and parses it in order to assign the correct path for each breadcrumb (except the last one)
- If the current path does not contain enough "subpaths" to satisfy the number of labels passed in, I've chosen not to render the component. For example, the component would not render if the current path was only `/system-settings/display` when `labels` contained three items.

Ultimately, the component would look like this when rendered (I haven't yet implemented the arrows between each breadcrumb):

```
Settings > System settings > Display
```

In this scenario, "Display" would be the currently viewed page. And the user would be able to click on "Settings" or "System settings" in order to jump to those respective pages.

I'd love to get feedback on my implementation. I'm also interested in learning more about best coding practices and whether there are any strong code smells in my component (and if there is one, why it is considered a code  smell).

Some areas that I think might be code smells but am not really sure if they are or why they are:

- Calling `pathNameIdx--` both inside the `while` loop and then again once the loop is exited
- Having a `return` statement in multiple places in my component (in my case, in just two places)
- Using a regular `for` loop instead of other forms like `for..of`, `for..in`, or `.forEach`.

````
import React from "react";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const RouteBreadcrumbs = ({labels = []}) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const history = useHistory();
    const pathName = location.pathname;

    const numBackslash = (pathName.match(/\//g) || []).length;
    if (numBackslash < labels.length) {
        return null;
    }

    let breadcrumbPaths = [];
    let pathNameIdx = pathName.length - 1;
    for (let i = labels.length - 1; i > 0 ; i--) {
        while ((pathName[pathNameIdx] !== "/")) {
            console.assert(pathNameIdx >= 0, "pathNameIdx is no longer a valid index");
            pathNameIdx--;
        }

        const newPath = pathName.substring(0, pathNameIdx);
        breadcrumbPaths = [newPath, ...breadcrumbPaths];
        pathNameIdx--;
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            {labels.map((label, idx) => <h5 key={idx} onClick={idx < breadcrumbPaths.length ? () => history.push(breadcrumbPaths[idx]) : null} className={"label2"}>{label}</h5>)}
        </div>
    )
};

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking pretty good. Here's a handful of suggestions you could try:

This part

```
{labels.map((label, idx) => <h5 key={idx} onClick={idx < breadcrumbPaths.length ? () => history.push(breadcrumbPaths[idx]) : null} className={"label2"}>{label}</h5>)}
```

is a really long line of code. Try breaking it up, it makes it easier to read.

```
{labels.map((label, idx) => (
  <h5
    key={idx}
    onClick={
      idx < breadcrumbPaths.length
        ? () => history.push(breadcrumbPaths[idx])
        : null
    }
    className={"label2"}
  >
    {label}
  </h5>
))}
```

(I tend to prefer 2-space indentation with javascript and HTML as they both tend to be indentation heavy, and it seems to be a more common in the javascript community - so I'll use that in these examples)

Also, refrain from using an index for an element key when possible ([the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) talk about why). You could instead use the breadcrumbPath, as that would be unique to each element, and the keys would correctly change when the path changes.

```
{labels.map((label, idx) => (
  <h5
    key={breadcrumbPaths[idx]}
    onClick={...}
    className={"label2"}
  >
    {label}
  </h5>
))}
```

You have some logic in there to calculate the number of backslashes a URL contains, but if you just wait a little bit on that early return, you will already have easy access to that number, as its the same as `breadcrumbsPath.length + 1`

```
if (breadcrumbPaths.length + 1 < labels.length) {
  return null;
}
```

On that note, this function won't handle the case correctly when there's a leading slash on the URL (i.e. 'example.com/a/b/') - that'll need to be taken care of. If you use the above code snippet, then you will only need to fix this issue in one place instead of two - where you create the breadcrumbPaths array.

To address your concern of having multiple returns: there's nothing wrong with having multiple returns like that in a function - in fact, it can often lead to cleaner code. Often, the alternative means large if-thens or flag variables, both of which are much harder to follow. I've heard that once upon a time a function with a single exit used to be something encouraged, but that's not the case anymore.

Now onto the part that you probably care about most - what to do about that chunk of logic with the c-style for loop, and multiple `pathNameIdx--`s.

First things first, I would probably break the meat of that logic out into a helper function. There's a lot of low-level work going on there that gets in the way of reading and understanding your component.

Here's how your component might look after doing that

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const RouteBreadcrumbs = ({labels = []}) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const pathName = location.pathname;

  const breadcrumbPaths = ancestorPaths(pathName);
  if (breadcrumbPaths.length + 1 < labels.length) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {labels.map((label, idx) => (
        <h5
          key={breadcrumbPaths[idx]}
          onClick={
            idx < breadcrumbPaths.length
              ? () => history.push(breadcrumbPaths[idx])
              : null
          }
          className={"label2"}
        >
          {label}
        </h5>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

function ancestorPaths(pathName) {
  let breadcrumbPaths = [];
  let pathNameIdx = pathName.length - 1;
  while (true) {
    while (pathName[pathNameIdx] !== "/") {
      if (pathNameIdx === 1) {
        return breadcrumbPaths;
      }
      pathNameIdx--;
    }

    const newPath = pathName.slice(0, pathNameIdx);
    breadcrumbPaths = [newPath, ...breadcrumbPaths];
    pathNameIdx--;
  }
}
```

Notice how there's a lot less low-level logic going on in the actual RouteBreadcrumbs component? It's a lot easier to read through it and get a good idea of what's going on - except for maybe the actual jsx getting returned - it's a little too nested for my liking, but it'll get simplified in a bit.

A couple other things I'll note with your original code:

- Prefer string.slice() over string.substring() - it has fewer quarks
- Good use of console.assert() there. The one thing I dislike about console.assert() is that it doesn't actually throw an error, it just logs one. Sometimes this isn't a big deal, here it is. If that assertion happened to come true, it would be stuck in an infinite loop, logging forever. You can just do `if (condition) throw new Error(...)` instead, or make your own assert function that actually throws an error.

Now lets look at simplifying our new ancestorPaths() helper function. It is possible to use regex to gather the indicies of all the slashes, which would work similar to how you have it, but greatly simplify the logic (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410464/how-to-find-indices-of-all-occurrences-of-one-string-in-another-in-javascript)). I'm going to instead just split on '/', build a list, and use a generator function, as follows:

```
function* iterAncestorPaths(pathName) {
  const parts = pathName.split("/").filter(x => x !== "");
  for (let i = 1; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    yield "/" + parts.slice(0, i).join("/");
  }
}
```

Note that the `.filter()` at the beginning will take care of both the leading `/` and a potential trailing slash.

One final thing: If your breadcrumb segments are links, why not make them actual links? it'll simplify some things.

Here's the final solution, with a couple other misc tweaks.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const RouteBreadcrumbs = ({labels = []}) => {
  const pathName = useLocation().pathname;

  const ancestorPaths = [...iterAncestorPaths(pathName)];
  if (ancestorPaths.length + 1 < labels.length) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {ancestorPaths.map((path, idx) => (
        <Link key={path} to={path} className="label">
          {labels[idx]}
        </Link>
      ))}
      <span className="label">{labels[labels.length - 1]}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

function* iterAncestorPaths(pathName) {
  const parts = pathName.split("/").filter(x => x !== "");
  for (let i = 1; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    yield "/" + parts.slice(0, i).join("/");
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for such a thorough response! Your suggestions all make sense, and the revised code looks a lot more concise. I'll need to read up on generator functions as I've never used one before. I was wondering what your thoughts are on defining helper functions inside versus outside of the component? In the case above, you decided to define `iterAncestorPaths` outside of the component. I'm assuming that was to declutter `RouteBreadcrumbs`. But are there circumstances where it makes sense to define it inside instead?

Comment: It depends on a few things: How many props/local variables does it need access to (An inner function has much easier access to these variables)? How well can the function be understood if it stands by itself? How big is the function? Is the component already large or cluttered? Is the module already cluttered? I generally prefer trying to keep components smaller, so I normally lean towards having the functions stand by themselves, but I am weighing all of those factors in when I make this decision.

Comment: As for generators, it would be healthy to read up one them, as they occasionally come in handy. The more you know, the more power to you :). Though, in this particular instance, it wouldn't be difficult to build and return an array of results inside of iterAncestorPaths() instead.